# Why doesn't this array need [NSArray array]?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

This is a little part of the code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSProcessInfo *proc = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
        NSArray *myArray = [proc arguments];
        ...
```

Why isn't it written like `NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [proc arguments]];`? Also, with ARC does that mean arrays don't need their `init` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `[proc arguments];` already returns an `NSArray *`. Writing `NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [proc arguments]];` is just redundant.